# Is it possible to export styled vector data as tif in QGIS without losing transparency?

Tags: qgis, vector, export, print-composer, transparency-opacity

I have vector point data which I have styled using svg images, see below with the globe in the background:

[image]

And without:

[image]

I want to export the image without the globe as a tif with transparency. The white should be 100% transparent while the edges around the data should keep there semi-transparency.

I have tried "save image as", which doesn't keep transparency and is to low resolution. Then I tried the following command:

```
.\qgis.bat --project D:\test\hurricanes\hurricanes_test.qgs --snapshot D:\test\hurricanes\hurricanes_new.tif --width 30000 --height 15000
```

I was able to increase the resolution this way, but again it doesn't keep transparency. I have tried using the background setting in the print composer, but it doesn't keep the semi-transparent edges around the data. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I think you want to produce an image of your data with transparency, but not a raster in the way a raster is understood in GIS terms. So the print composer is the right approach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve the transparency by using the map composer you need to set two things:

1. In the print composer window, change the `Page background` in the composition tab
   [image]
   [image]
2. Also change the selection of `Background`in the Item properties to unseleced
   [image]

I tested it and it worked fine in QGIS 2.18.7